# Release Pipeline unpack the zip and replace azure and connect the linux server throught ssh to copy files

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I need to unzip the build zip file and replace the variables define in release pipeline by using replace token task in properties file after that i need to deployed in linux server by using ssh copy files task.

Below are the steps I am doing

1. I created extract file task there i mention **Destination folder** : $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
2. After that i created replace token task **Root directory** given  $(Build.SourcesDirectory) from this directory find the properties file and replace the variables
3. Then I created copy files to over SSH here i gave **Source folder** $(Build.SourcesDirectory) to **Target folder** /home/*******/******-CICD ( deployment folder path in linux server).

Is this a correct apporach? do we have anyother option for this requirment.

please guide me .